# When setting up DNSSEC on Bind, which DNSKEY records belong in the zone file?

Tags: bind, dnssec

Should the zone file only contain the KSK's DNSKEY record, or should it contain the ZSK's DNSKEY record as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All.

Because the parent has a `DS`  record which is, in summary, a hash of the KSK. Hence, when following the chain of trust the recursive resolve will fetch that `DS` record from parent, and will fetch the `DNSKEY` record from child, and will check that there is at least one key in the `DNSKEY` record matching the `DS` record and then continue the validation (or else fail it immediately there).

Per §2.1.1. of RFC4034, each `DNSKEY` record has a flags attribute that will allow a resolver to know if this given crypto material is for a zone key or a key signing key.

Note that the KSK/ZSK split is common, but not the only case. You have also a CSK situation with C=Common where you have a single key, that both signs directly all other records and also has a matching `DS` record at parent.

Both are valid setups, with different benefits and drawbacks.

Also note that the `DNSKEY` record set can even contain keys not yet used for signing nor being at parent in a `DS` record, which happens for example during rotation (you first need to introduce the key in the zone and let resolvers cache it, then after some time you can begin signing with it, and then again after some time you can enable the relevant `DS` record if needed).